# How to send the inputbox value to a javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript, dom

Given this html...

```
<input id="txtbox-page" maxlength="4" />
```

how can I create a button or a link that executes a javascript function, where its parameter is the input box value?

I have to call a function, that is already in production, that has this format:

```
javascript:pageClient('?p=2');
```

where the number 2, has to be the value of the input box.

Comment: How about you wrap pageClient with another function that reads input box value and call pageClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<button id="pageClientSubmitter">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
var pageClientSubmitter = document.getElementById('pageClientSubmitter');

pageClientSubmitter.onclick = function () {
  var val = document.getElementById('txtbox-page').value;
  pageClient('?p=' + val);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/AS6TN/1/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<a id="mylink" href="foo.bar">Link</a>
```

JS:

```
var box = document.getElementById('txtbox-page');
document.getElementById('mylink').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Use `box` here
    pageClient('?p=' + +box.value);
}, false);
```

<sub>The second `+` is optional. I used it to convert to number in order to avoid injection attacks.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines:

```
function GetTxtBoxValue() {
    var txtBoxPage = document.getElementByID("txtbox-page");
    pageClient('?p='+txtBoxPage.value);
}
```

Then bind that function to your form submission.